# Downloading page in cromedriver is empty in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I've used **robcherry/docker-chromedriver** docker to simulate chrome browser and custom docker witch runs **Selenium IDE** tests.

My test clicks on file with link, waits until it has been downloaded and opens chrome://downloads/ page. 
When I run test locally(using cmd selenium-side-runner command and chromedriver which is downloaded by npm command) files appear in the list, but when I run it in docker compose, downloads list is empty.

What kind of settings should be set in docker to make files be downloaded?

This is part of page that I've got in docker. **downloads-manager** tag doesn't contain list of files.

> ```
>    <title>Downloads</title>
>    <link rel="stylesheet" href="chrome://resources/css/text_defaults_md.css">
>    <style>
>      html {
>        --downloads-card-margin: 24px;
>        --downloads-card-width: 680px;
>        background: #f1f1f1;
>
>        /* Remove 300ms delay for 'click' event, when using touch interface. */
>        touch-action: manipulation;
>      }
>
>      .loading {
>        /* --google-blue-700 disguised. Replaced when downloads-toolbar loads. */
>        border-top: 56px solid rgb(51, 103, 214);
>      }
>
>      html:not(.loading),
>      body {
>        height: 100%;
>      }
>
>      body {
>        display: flex;
>        margin: 0;
>      }
>    </style>
>  </head>
>  <body>
>    <downloads-manager></downloads-manager>
>
>
>    <command id="clear-all-command" shortcut="Alt|c"></command>
>    <command id="undo-command" shortcut="Ctrl|z"></command>
>    <command id="find-command" shortcut="Ctrl|f"></command>
>
>    <div hidden="" by-polymer-bundler=""><link rel="import" href="chrome://resources/html/polymer.html"><script> src="chrome://resources/js/load_time_data.js"></script>
>  <script src="chrome://downloads/strings.js"></script>
> ```

Comment: Any luck. I am also facing same issue.

Comment: @SaurabhShrivastava How do you handle with that?